# PHP: Laravel how to eager load find method

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have a model `Users` which has-many `Pages`, I want to eager load the method below so that it returns only a single user with all the pages eager loaded, how do I go about it.

```
$user = User::find(1);
$pages = $user->pages();
foreach($pages as $page) {
  var_dump($page->name);
}
```

What I tried but doesnt work, it loads everything instead:

```
$user = User::with('Pages')->get();
$pages = $user->pages();
```

Comment: You have to call it as an attribute and not a function `$user->pages`

Comment: Oh and also you have to do User::find(1)->with('Pages')->get(); so you just get one user

Comment: @Bogdan `pages` belongs to `user`

Comment: And does user `hasMany` pages?

Comment: @FabioAntunes I tried your suggestion , `User::find(1)->with('Pages')->get(); ` returns a collection instead

Comment: The instead of get() use first()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Drop the parenthesis.

```
$user = User::find(1);
$pages = $user->pages;
foreach($pages as $page) {
    var_dump($page->name);
}
```

If you want to eager load it, then use the `with` method and pass the correct parameter, which would be the name of your relationship methods:

```
$user = User::with('pages')->find(1);
foreach($user->pages as $page) {
    var_dump($page->name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKim, I really appreciate, works as I want

Comment: This was helpful. I was wrong to assume that `User::find(1)->with('pages');` would work the same way.

Comment: Ahh, I find myself back here at this question again. This time it was to learn that this works (camelCased): `$contact = \App\Models\Contact::with('callFlow')->find($this->contactId);` while this does not: `$contact = \App\Models\Contact::with('call_flow')->find($this->contactId);`