# Laravel Eloquent - using "With" along with "find"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Although a similar question is asked but in a different context here. [Laravel Eloquent with and find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864010/laravel-eloquent-with-and-find)

Issue I am having right now is that when I use **"find"**, it returns the object and not the collection.

```
MyModel::find($myId)
```

But when I use **"with"** it returns me the collection. Shouldn't be a single object with eager loading all the required data ?

```
MyModel::find($myId)->with('notes')
```

I am expecting it to return a single object with eager loading the notes. But its returning the collection. So I have to get the first object of the collection and then the eager loaded notes in it. But when I do something like

```
MyModel::find($myId)->with('notes')->first()
```

It returns the single object, which is correct, but doesn't make sense to me as I have read on laracast forum that **"first"** behind the scene uses **"find"**. So do I really need to use **"find"** and **"first"** together to get the required data or is there something I am doing wrong ?

**P.S** I am using Laravel 5.3

Comment: Try MyModel::with('notes')->find($myId);

Comment: Great, it did work. But can you please explain the flow behind these two methodologies?

Comment: It is already been mentioned by Alexey Mezenin.

Comment: Yes, just seen. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This explained it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617150/php-laravel-how-to-eager-load-find-method/34617322#comment95851422_34617322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it this way to get an object with collection:

```
MyModel::with('notes')->find($myId);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

And this should just return query builder instance:

```
MyModel::find($myId)->with('notes')
```

Comment: Yup, It did work. The one I posted is what I saw in one of the laracast videos but it was not using "with". Thanks for the correction.