# Laravel eager loading is not working on mssql

Tags: laravel-8

Laravel Framework 8.61.0

#### Model/Order.php

```php
<?php

class Order extends Model
{
    public client(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class, 'customer_fk', 'customer_key');
    }
}
```

This is a simple example for me to build the relationship with order and client, I can get client name without using eager loading, which means the relationship should be correct, but I don't want to have N+1 problems so I need eager loading, it's working perfectly on the same version of PHP and Laravel on MySQL, how to fix it on mssql?

```php
<?php

$order = Order::find(1);

echo $order->client->name; // return correct name

$order = Order::with(['client'])->find(1);

echo $order->client->name; // ErrorException : Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

Comment: Are you sure that worked with a different DB?  Bcs AFAIK that is not how to do with/find, eg a quick search shows:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864010/laravel-eloquent-with-and-find

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent with and find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864010/laravel-eloquent-with-and-find)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/fLUHvqy.png

it's work on MySQL